# MySQL Group by one column but select all the other data and sum it

Tags: mysql

I have a table, which looks like this:

```
studentid | studentname | fee | latfeecharges | dues
1         | Alex        | 2000 | 200           | 500
1         | Alex        | 2000 | 200           | 500
1         | Alex        | 2000 | 200           | 500
```

and I want the following result:

```
Alex

2700
2700
2700
```

So in this case, the `fee`, `latefeecharges` and `dues` are summed and I get them separately but want to get the name only one time. How do I do that?

right now im getting this result by using this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table  ORDER BY studentid ";
```

```
alex
2700
alex
2700
alex
2700
```

Comment: Doing this without dynamic MySQL or a language such as PHP could be a real pain.  Why do you need this formatting style?

Comment: i am making defaulters lists of students so i want to get all the previous dues which a particular student has not paid and make a report of it ... the report should show the total dues with the months of which the dues are not paid...

Comment: right now im getting the following result...          alex 2700   alex 2700 alex 2700 .... but i need ... alex 2700 2700 2700

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a month in your table or some way of deriving it you could use condional aggregation
so given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+-----------+-------------+------+----------------+------+------+
| studentid | studentname | fee  | latefeecharges | dues | MTH  |
+-----------+-------------+------+----------------+------+------+
|         1 | Alex        | 2000 |            200 |  500 |    1 |
|         1 | Alex        | 2000 |            200 |  500 |    2 |
|         1 | Alex        | 2000 |            200 |  500 |    3 |
+-----------+-------------+------+----------------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select studentname,
    -> sum(case when mth = 1 then fee+latefeecharges+dues else 0 end) month1,
    -> sum(case when mth = 2 then fee+latefeecharges+dues else 0 end) month2,
    -> sum(case when mth = 3 then fee+latefeecharges+dues else 0 end) month3
    -> from t
    -> group by studentname;
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| studentname | month1 | month2 | month3 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Alex        |   2700 |   2700 |   2700 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```